# OpenGL Newbie Questions about models

Tags: opengl, 3d

Part of a project I am working on involves displaying and rotating a human body, then pointing  with color or zooming to one or more parts of it. All this for iPhone or Android.

So far I have not used OpenGL because my 3D drawing is simpler, I know the math behind 3d project and stuff. I 've not worked with models, but I 've  found some human body models online.

My questions are:

- What would be the best file format to look for to achieve my goal?
- Can I access that models' vertices of interest so I can tell OpenGL to zoom at them or color them appropriately? Or the model is manipulated as a "single object" which can't break apart?
- Some sample would help, although I will start looking for the functions myself.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the 'best' file format, this is subjective. Use whatever format you can find that you also have a parser available for. OBJ is popular for simple models, though you may need something more complex if you need more features like animation. I guess it all depends on what you can find online.

OpenGL itself has no concept of models. It only accepts lists of vertices to render in triangles. Therefore the model is not a 'single object', as all of the information about the model must be broken down into vertices by your own code before it can be passed to OpenGL.

You can zoom to or color all the vertices in any way that you wish to do so in your own code, as all the vertices must pass through your code to get to the renderer.